# Array length 20 but i want it to break once it has read the last node

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

```
public void showAll(){//to string method
    for (int i=0;i<phoneBook.length;i++){//index is going till 2 where it   
        System.out.println(phoneBook[i].toString());
    }
    //the above code iterates for 20 times because the length of the array is 20.
    public phoneBookUnsoterdOptimizedArray( )
    {  
        next = 0;
        size = 20;//this initializes the array to size 20.
        phoneBook = new PhoneBook[size];
    }//end of constructor
```

I tried an `if` statement checking `null`, but that doesn't work.

**Output**

```
Phone Number: 4695866399
lastName: Ayoub
First Name: Rehan
address: 9323 Amberton Pkwy
Exception in thread "main" Phone Number: 971506236329
lastName: Ayoub
First Name: Syed
address: 14th Street Nyadat
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at phonebook.phoneBookUnsoterdOptimizedArray.showAll(phoneBookUnsoterdOptimizedArray.java:74)
    at phonebook.FA2015PROJECT_Ayoub.main(FA2015PROJECT_Ayoub.java:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly check for `null`s:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneBook.length; i++) {
    if (phoneBook[i] == null) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(phoneBook[i].toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers posted here will solve your problem, but here is an alternative.

If you are planning to `break` out of the loop only to avoid `NullPointerException`, you could alternatively use

```
String.valueOf(phoneBook[i])
```

instead of

```
phoneBook[i].toString()
```